# Firebase: Code/Formula to convert realtime database timestamp to firestore timestamp?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am running a web app on Firebase and I started on realtime database, and now I am migrating my data to firestore.

I migrated all the other data except for timestamp using admin SDK. In my web app, when a user uploads new content, the code adds timestamp to the database so that the contents can be sorted by time.

The problem is that realtime database and firestore apparently use different methods in logging timestamp:

```
firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP // This will be in the following format: 1577778747131 
firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now() // This will be in the following format: December 31, 2019 at 4:52:00 PM UTC + 9
```

Another problem is that firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now() apparently isn't stored in milliseconds or nanoseconds but in actual date and time in the system. So, I don't know what value, if any, to feed when writing to firestore instead of firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now().

What would be the code, in Javascript, to convert the timestamp values from realtime database to firebase timestamp? Basically, what would be the code to fill in the blank below:

```
postinfo.forEach(pi=>{
   const a = pi.time; //Timestamp stored  in realtime database format.
   /*
   Code to transform the timestamp in realtime database to the format to be uploaded to firestore. This I don't know yet.
   */
   const b = new_time;
   // Some code to log the new time instead of the old time. This I can take care of.
```

I can take time to user one of the converters available online and manually log the times in the new format, but it will take hours and it is not something a programmer would want to do. Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server timestamp that you would specify in Realtime Database as ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is known in Firestore as [FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#servertimestamp).

Timestamps in Firestore are not stored as unix time in milliseconds like Realtime Database.  They are stored using two number, offset in seconds and nanoseconds as described in the API documentation for [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp).  Use that Timestamp object when reading timestamp type fields out of Firestore.

Read more about how Firestore server timestamps work in [this article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-secrets-of-firestore-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-revealed-29dd7a38a82b).